# Why Delimeter in For Doesn't Work?

Tags: batch-file, delimiter

I am trying to divide a file by the delimiter ":", but it seems to divide it by the lines.

Here is my code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%x in (SomeFile.txt) DO echo %%x
```

Here is "SomeFile.txt":
1:2:3:4:5:6:7
8:9:10:11:12:13:14
...

I expect it to be:

1
2
3
4
5
...

But I get the file as it was:
1:2:3:4:5:6:7
8:9:10:11:12:13:14
...

what is the explanation for this?

Comment: Besides the different number of tokens, the other question perfectly demonstrates how to split a text file into tokens using delimiters. Have you ever read the help text when typing `for /?` into a command prompt window?

Answer (score 1):

`For /f` reads lines from the file and tokenises them according to the delimiter-set and `tokens` setting.

Since you use `tokens=*`, all of the tokens are assigned to the *metavariable* `%%x`.

It would be better had you posted realistic data as a solution may be influenced by the actual data format, but in order to produce your results, another approach would be:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q44868366.txt"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filename1%) do CALL :uncolon "%%a"
    )

GOTO :EOF

:uncolon
SET "line=%~1"
FOR %%t IN ("%line::=" "%") DO ECHO %%~t
goto :eof
```

(I set the variable `filename1` to a file containing your data for testing)

Here, each line in turn is assigned to `%%a`, and then processed by the subroutine `:uncolon`

The subroutine accepts the first parameter to `line` and removes the enclosing quotes with the `~` modifier.

The variable `line` then has each colon replaced by `" "` and the resultant string itself enclosed in double-quotes. The result is a series of quoted strings which a simple `for` then processes , assigning each in turn to `%%t` and the `echo` produces a line for each, with the enclosing quotes again removed by `~`.

...But a lot depends on the actual data involved.